# Cannot install any extension, Bolt complains about "Malformed JSON response"

Tags: bolt-cms

I just did a fresh install of Bolt on a separate subdomain with my regular webhoster. I want to install the 'Simone' theme but for some reason this won't work. I can select a version of the theme, after which a "Installing package" window appears that does not quit and never gets beyond 0%.

I suspect this has something to do with an error that's under "Your currently installed extensions". It says:

> Malformed JSON response. Ensure no debugging or other code is being added to the response

I did disable debug mode in config.yml, to no avail. I found a [bug report](https://github.com/bolt/bolt/issues/3501) that seems close to what I'm describing, but I can't get anything to install *at all*.

I can reproduce this reliably. I don't seem to be doing anything out of the ordinary:

1. created a new database + user
2. CLI: mkdir bolt && cd bolt
3. CLI: curl -O http://bolt.cm/distribution/bolt-latest.tar.gz
4. CLI: tar -xzf bolt-latest.tar.gz --strip-components=1
5. CLI: chmod -R 777 files/ app/database/ app/cache/ app/config/ theme/ extensions/
6. edited .htaccess to include RewriteBase / (otherwise redirect won't work)
7. visited my new website at bolt.mydomain.com, be presented with user screen, not creating a new user
8. edited app/config/config.yml: Changed database to driver mysql, with databasename, username, password, host.
9. changed debug in config.yml from true to false
10. revisit /bolt/userfirst, create first user
11. first login with new credentials

Went to /bolt/extend. Under *Currently installed extensions* it says: "Malformed JSON response. Ensure no debugging or other code is being added to the response."

Tried installing Simone theme. Won't work.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

That should only be happening if you're using an `echo` or `dump()` somewhere in the code path. I just tried on v2.2.10 and that theme installs and generates correctly.

Comment: I've included steps to reproduce. I don't see where I could've added echo or dump().

Comment: Also verified this with v2.2.10 from http://bolt.cm/distribution/bolt-2.2.10.tar.gz. Same issue. I have some programming skills, so I can help debug, but I'm not sure I am able to track this down myself.

Comment: If you're using Chrome or Firefox you press F12 and that will open the developer console, click the `Network` tab.

Do this when you have the `Installing package` dialogue up and press the `Install` button and that will show you the response from the server… the "Malformed JSON response. Ensure no debugging or other code is being added to the response" is added in the client JavaScript for a response it can't process.

Comment: TypeError: a[0] is undefined. Occurs in /app/view/js/bolt.min.js at :5:11651

Comment: Can we get a screenshot of the entire thing in the debug console? And also the actual _response_?

Comment: Sure! I hope [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/er7Zgp6.png) offers more info, I'm not entirely sure this is what you requested.

Comment: The screenshot is indeed what i wanted to see. Unfortunately, i was expecting to see a malformed JSON result, but it seems fine. I'm puzzled.

Would it be possible for me to get temporary access to the subsite, to see with my own eyes? Feel free to drop me a line at bob [@] bolt.cm.

Comment: No problem, I just sent you an email